# How do I filter my XML list to not get duplicate letters returned case insensitively

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I've got some XML that has an Alphabetically ordered list of strings. I want to generate a set of Divs containing the first letter of each set with no duplicate first letters.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<textstring>
  <example>Delta</example>
  <example>delta2</example>
  <example>harmony</example>
  <example>incognito</example>
  <example>Inconvenient</example>
</textstring>
```

**XSL**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="textstring">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="trick" select="/textstring/example"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/textstring/example" mode="trick">
      <xsl:variable name="firstLetter" select="substring(text(),1,1)"/>
        <div>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$firstLetter"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
D
d
h
i
I
```

**Desired Output**

```
D
H
I
```

I was thinking of something that would add to the select such as

```
<xsl:template match="textstring">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="trick" select="/textstring/example[not(starts-with(
         substring(
           translate(text(), 
             'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') ,1,1),
         substring(following-sibling::example[
           translate(text(), 
             'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') ],1,1)
    ))]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But that results in

```
D
d
h
```

Am I completely off base?  I didn't really want to switch to a for-each loop since it is somewhat resource intensive, but is checking preceding sibling really any less so?

Comment: IMHO, you should use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told in the comment you should use the [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). See the next XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="first-letters" match="example" use="substring(translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 1, 1)" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="textstring">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="example[generate-id() = generate-id(key('first-letters', substring(translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 1, 1))[1])]" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="example">
        <div>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(translate(., 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), 1, 1)" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will generate the required output:

```
<div>D</div>
<div>H</div>
<div>I</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely a solution.  I'm curious about the impact on performance by grouping in this way. In the end I should only end up with something like 26 keys. So it shouldn't be too bad I'd think.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Joshua: Using the Muenchian Method is the only and best way to go even for performance. If you are satisfied with this answer, don't forget to accept the answer (click the green tick beside the answer)

Comment: Yeah, it answers my question.  Not sure if it fits my exact non-example scenario (I do require the mode="trick" call) but if not I'll open a new question with more specific details. Thanks!

Comment: A small nitpick: you should do substring() first, then translate().

Comment: That was a modification I made to the final version :)